# Cant swap image on click if div is visible

Tags: jquery

Im trying to swap the image if #filters is visible, but its not working, no errors in console...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#filter-options :checkbox").click(function(){
    $("#product-list li").hide();
    $("#filter-options :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
      $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });

    if($('#filter-options :checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
      $("#product-list li").fadeIn();
    }
  });

  $('.col').on('click', function(){

    $('#filters').slideToggle(200);

    if($('#filters').is(':visible')){
      $('.col').attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png');
    }

    else{
      $('.col').attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/open_round.png');
    }

  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/594yj9uL/9/

Comment: Can also move the slideToggle() after the visibility check and attain same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), in case of `slideToggle()`, you need to check the visibility and the end of the animation using the complete callback option

```
$('.col').on('click', function () {

    $('#filters').slideToggle(200, function(){
        console.log($(this).is(':visible'))
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $('.col').attr('src', 'http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png');
        } else {
            $('.col').attr('src', 'http://www.asus.com/media/images/open_round.png');
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/beL0jsy8/)

Comment: You got there first, Arun. Well done, once again! +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
$('#filters').slideToggle(200);
```

Because it takes 200ms for the element to be hidden, the remaining code executes and finds the element still visible.

If you wrap the next bit in a `setTimeout`, you will solve the problem.

```
$('.col').on('click', function(){
    $('#filters').slideToggle(200);

    setTimeout(function(){
        alert( $('#filters').is(':visible') );

        if($('#filters').is(':visible')){
            $('.col').attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png');
        }else{
            $('.col').attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/open_round.png');
        }
    },500);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/594yj9uL/10/)

Comment: @john Note that Arun's answer of using a callback is a better solution. I'll leave mine visible for sake of interest / amusement.

Answer (score 1):

Working example in **[`**FIDDLE**`](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/3e7dmdu9/)**

Mainly idea is put condition into slideToggle callback function

### Javascript

```
if($('#filter-options :checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
  $("#product-list li").fadeIn();
}

$('.col').on('click', function(){
  var self = $(this); 
  $('#filters').slideToggle(200, function(){          
    if($('#filters').is(':visible')){
      self.attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png');
    } else {
      self.attr('src','http://www.asus.com/media/images/open_round.png');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: how different is your ans from @arun ans?? except for using this key word??

Comment: The same solution, but from different developers. The answer is pretty straightforward.